# Position-dependent Lagrange multipliers for functionals

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to extremise the functional

$$ S = \int L(Q_i) \, dx\,dy $$

Where the $Q_i$ are functions of $x$ and $y$, subject to the constraint

$$ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{Q} = A(x,y) \,.$$

My approach has been to define the functional

$$F = \int  \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{Q} - A(x,y) \, dx \,dy $$

Which means the constraint can be written as $F = 0$. Then to solve the problem we need to extremise without constraint the functional

$$ S + \lambda F$$

for some Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$. That is, we need to solve

$$ \frac{\delta S}{\delta Q_i} + \lambda \frac{\delta F}{\delta Q_i} = 0$$

for each $i$. However, because of the nature of $F$, its functional derivative is identically zero. This means that my Lagrange multiplier drops completely out of the problem, which can't be right. I have found answers to this question and the approach they take is to treat $\lambda = \lambda(x,y)$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, bringing it inside the integral in the expression for $F$. Then the variation of $F$ includes terms like

$$ \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x} \,.$$

I've never seen anything like this before --- I have always treated the Lagrange multiplier as some constant that sits outside the integral. Can anybody explain what is going on?

Thank you.